# Why is this simple counter counting an additional word?

Tags: javascript

The html:

[image]

I'm doing the following:

```
var words = $("#input-content > p").map(function() {
  return $.text(this);
}).get().join(" ");
```

which outputs:

> "one two three four "

I don't understand why doing:

```
words.split(" ").length
```

Outputs `5` when there're only `4` words.

Why is that? How to fix it?

Comment: Probably because there are four spaces in the string you're getting.

Comment: I guess a simple `trim()` could do the trick here: `word.trim().split(' ')`.

Comment: If you want to count words, you might consider a regular expression that matches words, such as `var words = s.match(/[\w-]+/g)`. Then you don't care about whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

String `"one two three four "` has a trailing space, which adds one extra empty string to the end of the resulting array, i.e. `["one", "two", "three", "four", ""]`.

In order to fix the problem consider using trimming function, like [`$.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) in jQuery.